# Error handler for insert into before deleting the records

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server table with application and push the data to oracle table (3rd party) using link-server. I want to set an error handler if insertion is not successful the delete query will not be executed. Here's my query run in SQL Server Agent every 24 hours.

```
DELETE FROM oracle_tbl
```

--If insert into is not successful then rollback else commit--

```
INSERT INTO oracle_tbl
SELECT*
FROM
sqlserver_tbl
```

Comment: So what is your question? "I want" doesn't ask any thing. What is the problem you are trying to solve, and why isn't what you have not working? What *is* your attempt to fix the problem?

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding, what I wanted is that if INSERT INTO is failed then the DELETE query won't be executed. Is there anyway, to handle the error? Let's say delete the record without commit if insert is successful then the delete will be committed otherwise delete no commit...something like that...

Comment: If the `DELETE` is after the `INSERT` it won't be executed if the `INSERT` fails.

Comment: I come up with these syntax BEGIN TRAN DELETE FROM oracle_tbl then INSERT INTO oracle_tbl FROM sqlserver_tbl if inserted successfully then BEGIN TRAN DELETE FROM oracle_tbl COMMIT TRAN else BEGIN TRAN DELETE FROM oracle_tbl ROLLBACK TRAN but I cannot incorporate these in one query...

Comment: YOu have 2 transaction. You should have one, and a `TRY...CATCH` block.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the outline of a stored procedure that will demonstrate the behavior you're looking for.  If the insert is not succcessful, i.e. 0 are rows are inserted, then an exception is thrown which will trigger the CATCH BLOCK which contains the rollback statement.  If the INSERT is successful then the DELETE statement executes.

```
drop proc if exists dbo.stored_procedure_name;
go
create proc dbo.stored_procedure_name
  @input                    nvarchar(max)=null,
  @test_id                  bigint output,
  @response                 nvarchar(max) output
as
set nocount on;
set xact_abort on;

begin transaction
begin try
    declare
      @o_id                 bigint,
      @o_count              bigint;

    /* attempt to insert into table */
    INSERT INTO oracle_tbl
    SELECT *
    FROM
    sqlserver_tbl;
    select @o_count=rowcount_big();
    select @o_id=cast(scope_identity() as bigint);

    /* if the insert failed, then throw an exception which rollback the transaction */
    if @o_count<>1
        throw 50000, 'No rows inserted', 1;

    /* delete from table */
    DELETE FROM oracle_tbl;

    select 
      @test_id=@o_id,
      @response=(select N'Ok' reply_message, @o_id o_id for json path, without_array_wrapper);      
    commit transaction;
end try
begin catch
    select 
      @test_id=cast(0 as bigint),
      @response=error_message() for json path, without_array_wrapper);

    rollback transaction;  
end catch
go
```

Comment: Hi Steve C, I'll try. Thank you.